# What Happens If A Pokéball Gets Stuck In A Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon

For example you had a real big brute of a Pokémon who wouldn’t listen to you and you accidently dropped your Pokéball on the ground and he ate it what would happen?

Comment: I imagine this would involve some expensive surgery at the vet's.

Answer (score 8):

Nom:

From [Whiscash and Ash](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/AG075)

> It doesn’t catch the Pokémon and presumably ends in digestive upset.